# How to create a persistent USB Installation from MAC?

Tags: usb, mac, persistence

With current instructions in ubuntu.com I know *how to create an USB to boot from MAC*. It works but **it is not a persistent installation**.

How can I make a persistent Ubuntu 13.4 Installation in a USB Key to work in MAC Book air?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "make it work"? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi FEichinger, With current instructions in Ubuntu.net I know how to create an USB to boot from MAC. It works but it is not a persistent installation. Everytime I boot up with it I need to reconfigure the WiFi, download my favorite apps, etc. I don´t know how to change my USB Live installation to a persistent one to be used in a MAC Book Air.

Comment: Have you tried the guide here? http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: @EliahKagan not sure those apply to mac's

Comment: @Braiam That's a good point. While [the master persistent USB creation question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) is still relevant and *ought* to contain information about persistent USB Ubuntu systems on Macs, the answers there are likely not sufficient. I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: As Braiam has recently pointed out in comments, that probably doesn't apply for Macs; in particular, the Universal USB Installer doesn't produce USB flash drives that are bootable on Macs. (Even UNetbootin, which has a version that *runs* on Macs, doesn't make USB flash drives that boot on them.) I wouldn't expect it to work for persistent USB's if it doesn't work for "regular" ones.

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution for your problem...

http://studyblast.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/guide-mac-os-x-lion-how-to-boot-a-linux-live-system-from-a-usb-drive-how-to-update-any-ocz-ssds-firmware/

copy the file in a usb flash drive in fat32 create the folder efi inside efi create folder boot and inside efi/boot put 2 files the linux distro renamed boot.iso and the file bootx64.efi...reboot holding option and select usb device:done!

Comment: Well, done after you edit the grub.cfg file to add the word "persistent". See bug #1159016.

Comment: nice find @ubfan1